# fixed effects ordinal regression in R

Tags: r, statistics, regression, ordinal

I'm trying to perform an ordinal regression with fixed effects in R. I'm not sure which package to use or which function. The general formula would be something like:

```
model <- ordinal(dependent ~ independent, index = "person", model = "within")
```

where:

"ordinal" is the function to use
"dependent" is the dependent variable
"independent" is independent variable
"index" is where the endogeneity is (the column to fix effects on)
"model = "within"" is fixed effects within index (i.e. within person)

Comment: `MASS::polr` or `ordinal::clm`? If you have a lot of dummies it would be useful to be able to use sparse model matrices, I don't know offhand which packages will support that ...

Comment: `plm`could work too to obtain fixed effects. It would be something like: `plm(dependent ~ independent,  data = df,  index = c("person", "time_var"),  model = "within")` where `person` is the variable you want to apply the fixed effects to.